# 関数の定義が意図した通りできない

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

関数を定義したいのですが、定義されません
（変数＋２）×４みたいに
以下が実際にやってみたコード？です

```
def sample function(data):
  return (data+2)*4
```

Comment: 空白入れずに 例えば `sample_function` のように定義してみると良いかも

Comment: 例えばこんな記事が参考になるでしょう。[Python命名規則一覧](https://qiita.com/naomi7325/items/4eb1d2a40277361e898b), [【Python】変数・関数・クラス・メソッドの命名規則（PEP-8）](https://algorithm.joho.info/programming/python/naming-conventions-pep-8/), [pep8-ja](https://pep8-ja.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/)

Comment: 関数を定義することそのものについてはこちら。[関数の定義](https://www.python.jp/train/function/index.html), [Python関数の基本：使い方と作り方・引数と戻り値【初心者編】](https://www.akkodis.co.jp/candidate/insight/column_121), [とほほのPython入門 - 関数](https://www.tohoho-web.com/python/function.html)

Answer (score 2):

質問者さんからの応答が未だのようですが、最初のコメントにUpvoteが付いているように、関数名に空白文字が入っていることが問題の原因です。

Pythonの仕様だとこの辺の記事が該当します。
[8.7. 関数定義](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions)

> ```
> funcdef    ::=  [decorators] "def" funcname "(" [parameter_list] ")"
>                 ["->" expression] ":" suite
> ```

> ```
> funcname   ::=  identifier
> ```

[2.3. 識別子 (identifier) およびキーワード (keyword)](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers)

> ASCII 範囲 (U+0001..U+007F) 内では、識別子として有効な文字は Python 2.x におけるものと同じです。大文字と小文字の`A`から`Z`、アンダースコア`_`、先頭の文字を除く数字`0`から`9`です。

このように「識別子として有効な文字」(関数名として使える文字)には「空白文字」は入っていません。

コメントに書かれているように「空白文字」をアンダースコア`_`に変えるか、「空白文字」を削除して2つの文字列を連結する等で対処できます。

他には私がコメントに書いたような記事や、以下のちょっと古い記事等も参考になるでしょう。
[Python公式ドキュメント内で書かれてる BNF](http://hhsprings.pinoko.jp/site-hhs/2015/11/python%E5%85%AC%E5%BC%8F%E3%83%89%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A5%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E5%86%85%E3%81%A7%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%82%8B-bnf/)